# How to transfer just OS (Windows 7) from bigger hdd (1TB) to smaller ssd (240GB)

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd

I want to move just the OS off a bigger HDD to a smaller SSD. My plan is to make the HDD a storage device and the SSD the OS bit to speed up the system and eventually upgrade to windows 10. Please give me a guide  on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a good time to do a clean installation of Windows 10 on the SSD, but if you're sure you want to stick with your current Windows 7 installation then you could:

1. Move all the non-OS data off the 1TB drive onto temporary storage somewhere. You'll need to get the size of all the data on the 1TB drive to less than then 240GB on the SSD
2. Boot [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/) off a USB stick and follow these instructions to do a [Disk to disk clone](https://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/03_Disk_to_disk_clone)
3. Boot off the SSD
4. Move the data back from the temporary storage onto your 1TB drive